# illustrator why when i click make to convert to live paint why does the stroke profile change

Tags: adobe-illustrator, colors, stroke

I have changed uniform line to shaped line profile and when I click make to convert to live paint I get a dialog box which says" complex visual appearance objects ... may be lost when converting to a live paint group. This has not happened in other files I am working on (athough plenaty of other things d0). I am new to illustrator. Is it to do with flattening? grouping? Please help!

Comment: No idea without seeing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I am so new I did not realise that. However I found that I when I expanded appearance again, it worked. I had already closed the programme and so on, and thought that I had also tried that again as well. Anyway that did the trick. Thanks very much for your response.